# Prevent future.get() from Making GUI Unresponsive in Order to Implement a Pause Button

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, executorservice, future

I am creating a program which takes parameters from the user, does some complex computations, and returns values to the user. Because these computations often take some time, I would like the user to be able to pause/resume or stop the computations at any time. I am using multi-threading to run the computations, but since I am using future.get() to retrieve the solutions, the GUI is unresponsive while the calculations are being done. Here is my code:

```
   System.out.println("Starting all threads...");
   ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
   int threadCount = 4;
   int amount = 10000000;
   StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
       Future<String> future = exec.submit(new Simulator(inputVariable1,inputVariable2, 
        inputVariable3, inputVariable4, inputVariable5, inputVariable6,    amount/threadCount)); 
   //No these are not the real variable names
        try {
            s.append(future.get()).append("\n");
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StartGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }
   int length = (int)(Math.log10(amount)+1);
   int start = 0;
   int totalWins = 0;
   int totalLosses = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
       int pos = s.indexOf("Wins: ",start);
       int end = s.indexOf("Losses: ",start);
       totalWins += Integer.parseInt(s.substring(pos+6,end-1));
       totalLosses += Integer.parseInt(s.substring(end+8,end+7+length));
   }
   println("Total wins: " + totalWins + "\n" + "Total losses: " + totalLosses);
```

As you can see, I am creating 4 threads, running the calculations in each thread, and then collecting the results from each using future.get(). The problem I am having is that I am unable to implement pause/resume/stop buttons into the GUI because the future.get() method makes the GUI unresponsive until it retrieves the data. Any ideas on what I can do to remedy this?

Comment: Just for the record, you can test the `Future` to see if it is done with `future.isDone()`.

Answer (score 4):

`Future#get` blocks until the `Callable` completes, this means, you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread until the `Callable` completes, meaning that UI can no longer respond to events being generated...

A better solution would be to use a `SwingWorker`, which is conceptually the same thing, except that it has functionality for providing feedback into the EDT, specifically, in this case the `done` method.  Which is called when the worker completes, but is called from within the context of the EDT, making it save to update the UI.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) in particular...

Comment: For some reason SwingWorker still makes the GUI unresponsive.

Comment: You're calling get from within the EDT? Not calling execute and using doInBackground instead? Would you like me to continue guessing or would be able to update your question?